Иконка Окна Sfml
Я создаю игру на Sfml + Cmake на Windows. И не знаю как при открытии файла .exe сделать отображение  своей иконку в панели быстрого доступа, помогите пожалуйста.

У окна в SFML есть этот замечательный метод:
void setIcon(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const Uint8 *pixels)

А у sf::Texture этот:
Image sf::Texture::copyToImage() const

А у sf::Image этот:
const Uint8 * sf::Image::getPixelsPtr() const

Соотвественно, если Вы загрузите текстуру и скопируете ее в изображение, то сможете установить иконку окну, получив у изображения указатель на массив пикселей. Это иконка окна будет отображаться в панели быстрого доступа, пока окно открыто (так же, как и с другими программами).
